# how to access user id value in another controller in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to access user login id (whenever he/she loggedin?) in some other controller
i tried so many methods

Answer (score 4):

Define a `current_user` method in your `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   helper_method :current_user

   def current_user
      # ...
      # return an instance of User class
      # can be just:
      # @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
      # if you set session[:user_id] when the user logs in
   end
end
```

This way you can access `current_user.id` inside other controllers.

Comment: You don't answer the question because it's assume he use some authentication plugin

Comment: I didn't assume he's using any plugins. If he has a login action, he's keeping the `user_id` somewhere. This is everything I've assumed.

Comment: Yes, regardless of whether he's using an authentication plugin, it's still perfectly valid to define `current_user`, and more than likely he is using a plugin anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You need use session.

You put your user id in session after login

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
```

And in all of your controller you can fetch you userid from this session

```
User.find(session[:user_id])
```

Comment: Please see my comment in my answer to reconsider your down vote. tks.